# Can I embed a Java CLI program in a web page?

Tags: java, web-applications, applet, executable-jar

I have a Java jar file that I run from a Windows command prompt: *java jar-file class args…*. I would like to use it in a web app, where it would run on the client side; more or less as an applet rather than a servlet. Is there an easy way to do this? Short of decompiling, I don't have access to the Java source code, but I would be willing to add additional classes to the jar file. One other complication: the arguments to the jar command include the names of an input and output file. I'm pretty sure I can replace them with i/o stream objects but a solution would need to translate data urls.

Comment: yes, it's easy. probably the jar file has a class with a main() method being executed, defined in it manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way to do this?

No.  You might write a (trusted) applet wrapper that redirects the system out and in streams to use them in the applet, but applets are never easy.